# Is it possible to clone a directory with netrw?

Tags: netrw, filesystem

When I mark a directory with `mf`, then use `mc` to copy into the target directory, it copies the contents only rather than the directory itself. I know I could make a new directory with `d`, then copy the files into it, but I'd rather clone the directory in one step if possible.

Comment: I think you're going to want [this](https://github.com/will133/vim-dirdiff) plugin for that. [Alternate location](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

Long answer:
This discussion [netrw copy commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958059/vim-netrw-copy-commands) clearly states, how this is accomplished with netrw (the target directory needs to be created first).

It is also lamented, that this is easier to achieve in NerdTree.
( <kbd>m</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> according to this answer [...duplicate ...entire folder...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115404/how-to-copy-or-duplicate-an-entire-folder-in-vim-using-nerdtree)).

The above mentioned `dir-diff` allows to sync directories.